# mouse coordinates in canvas not working

Tags: javascript, canvas

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var mouseX=0;
var mouseY=0;
var canvasPos=getPosition(canvas);

ctx.addEventListener("mousemove",setMousePosition,false);
function getPosition(e1) {
  var xPosition = 0;
  var yPosition = 0;

  while (e1) {
    xPosition += (e1.offsetLeft - e1.scrollLeft + e1.clientLeft);
    yPosition += (e1.offsetTop - e1.scrollTop + e1.clientTop);
    e1 = e1.offsetParent;
  }
  return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
}
function setMousePosition(e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX - canvasPos.x;
  mouseY = e.clientY - canvasPos.y;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF6A6A";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function getPosition(e1) {
  var xPosition=0;
  var yPosition=0;
  while(e1) {
    xPosition+=(e1.offsetLeft-e1.scrollLeft+e1.clientLeft);
    yPosition+=(e1.offsetTop-e1.scrollTop+e1.clientTop);
    e1=e1.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: xPosition,
    y: yPosition
  };
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

The goal is for a canvas element to follow the mouse movement. My attempt is pasted above. I tried retrieving the exact mouse coordinates and used it to re-draw the element. I don't seem to be getting any output, only a blank canvas. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had 2 typos:

1. `var context...`
2. `ctx.addEventListener(...)`

The: `ctx.addEventListener()` is not possible because of the context has no events.
The canvas does have those.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
// edit from context to ctx
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var mouseX=0;
var mouseY=0;
var canvasPos=getPosition(canvas);
// edit ctx to canvas
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",setMousePosition,false);
function getPosition(e1) {
  var xPosition = 0;
  var yPosition = 0;

  while (e1) {
    xPosition += (e1.offsetLeft - e1.scrollLeft + e1.clientLeft);
    yPosition += (e1.offsetTop - e1.scrollTop + e1.clientTop);
    e1 = e1.offsetParent;
  }
  return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
}
function setMousePosition(e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX - canvasPos.x;
  mouseY = e.clientY - canvasPos.y;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF6A6A";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function getPosition(e1) {
  var xPosition=0;
  var yPosition=0;
  while(e1) {
    xPosition+=(e1.offsetLeft-e1.scrollLeft+e1.clientLeft);
    yPosition+=(e1.offsetTop-e1.scrollTop+e1.clientTop);
    e1=e1.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: xPosition,
    y: yPosition
  };
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've to add event listener to `canvas` not to its context

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var mouseX=0;
var mouseY=0;
var canvasPos=getPosition(canvas);

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",setMousePosition,false); // <-- this
function getPosition(e1) {
  var xPosition = 0;
  var yPosition = 0;

  while (e1) {
    xPosition += (e1.offsetLeft - e1.scrollLeft + e1.clientLeft);
    yPosition += (e1.offsetTop - e1.scrollTop + e1.clientTop);
    e1 = e1.offsetParent;
  }
  return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
}
function setMousePosition(e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX - canvasPos.x;
  mouseY = e.clientY - canvasPos.y;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF6A6A";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function getPosition(e1) {
  var xPosition=0;
  var yPosition=0;
  while(e1) {
    xPosition+=(e1.offsetLeft-e1.scrollLeft+e1.clientLeft);
    yPosition+=(e1.offsetTop-e1.scrollTop+e1.clientTop);
    e1=e1.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: xPosition,
    y: yPosition
  };
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```